# How can I disable auto bracket closing in Ace editor?

Tags: jquery, ace-editor

I'm using ace to develop a collaborative code editor and each time I put an opening bracket a closing one pairs in and the cursor reaches the end. Please tell me if there's a way to disable the auto closing of brackets.

Thanks.

Heres what I've tried so far

```html
<script src="/ext-language_tools.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
      var editor = ace.edit("editor");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/github");
        editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
        editor.setOptions({
          fontSize: "15pt",
          enableBasicAutocompletion: false,
          enableLiveAutocompletion: false
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `behavioursEnabled: false` option https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Configuring-Ace